# AttributeError: partially initialized module 'face_recognition' has no attribute 'face_encodings'

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, face-recognition

I am trying to make face recognition script in python with the help of below given link found on google.
https://www.mygreatlearning.com/blog/face-recognition/

I have installed:

- **OpenCV**
- **dlib** and
- **face_recognition**

libraries.

Also, installed Visual C++ for CMake.

And now I am trying to "extract features from Face" using code given in above link.

While running script, I am getting below error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ajay.arora2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\extract_features_from_face.py", line 2, in <module>
    import face_recognition
  File "C:\Users\ajay.arora2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\face_recognition.py", line 32, in <module>
    encodings = face_recognition.face_encodings(rgb)
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'face_recognition' has no attribute 'face_encodings' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

I have tried re-installing face_recognition module.

Please suggest any workaround.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most probably you have named your file the same as the library "face_recognition".

Circular import happens when you want to import something from the same file.